# How to resolve an "Unsupported extension: RegularPatterns" error?

Tags: haskell

New to Haskell, but in F# one can pattern match for the equivalent of the following:

```
splitStr :: String -> String -> States -> String
splitStr ('\"':xs) acc (SentenceStart | SentenceMiddle) =
  splitStr xs acc Quoting
```

The Atom editor tells me to add the `{-# LANGUAGE RegularPatterns #-}` pragma at the top to make the above work. When I do that it tells me that it can't find the extension. Looking at the list of [known](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.2/docs/html/libraries/Cabal-1.14.0/Language-Haskell-Extension.html) extensions, it does not seem like `RegularPatterns` was added recently. I am using `7.10.3` version of GHC. I've also tried compiling and it won't work so the Atom editor is not at fault here.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: My 7.10.3 says `parse error on input '|'`, rather than suggesting the bogus extension. Is your editor using a linter of some sort? The suggestion to add `RegularPatterns` is a bug in *something*...

Comment: Actually, when I said that it did not seem like it was added recently, I meant that it was there for a while as it did not have a version number. It is right there in the documentation.

Comment: The link to docs in your post is for GHC 7.4.2, from 2012. [This](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/flag-reference.html#idp46686514436848) is a list of the latest flags. But this doesn't address the tool that suggested the extension in the first place.

Comment: I see, you are right. It might be worth reporting the bug then. I'll look into that tomorrow.

Comment: The question is who to report the bug to. It's doesn't appear to be GHC's fault.

Comment: The Atom editor and the Haskell extensions have their own Github pages, so I'll try the later tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you have these options.

Split the pattern. This is the simplest and most common option, unless the right hand side is very large. (When it is large, I'd still consider defining an auxiliary function just for that.)

```
splitStr ('\"':xs) acc SentenceStart  = splitStr xs acc Quoting
splitStr ('\"':xs) acc SentenceMiddle = splitStr xs acc Quoting
```

Use pattern guards and `where`.

```
splitStr ('\"':xs) acc s 
   | SentenceStart  <- s = result 
   | SentenceMiddle <- s = result
   where result = splitStr xs acc Quoting
```

Use view patterns

```
startOrMiddle SentenceStart  = True
startOrMiddle SentenceMiddle = True
startOrMiddle _              = False

splitStr ('\"':xs) acc (True <- startOrMiddle) =
   splitStr xs acc Quoting
```

Use pattern synonyms and view patterns

```
-- startOrMiddle as above

pattern StartOrMiddle = (True <- startOrMiddle)

splitStr ('\"':xs) acc StartOrMiddle = splitStr xs acc Quoting
```

Comment: This is a good answer. I read a bit about the `->` operator in this [tutorial](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/hask/),but it would not have occurred to me to use it for pattern matching even though I know that on the left side there is a lambda. That is pretty clever. Did `RegularPatterns` get removed or something?

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic I never saw that extension in GHC.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, `RegularPatterns` is an extension provided by HaRP preprocessor. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/harp

Project was all but abandoned around 2010 I think, but it's still somewhat maintained.

As for message itself, it seems to be a parse error generated by haskell-src-exts, used by hlint.